# Override plugin hooks in child theme

Tags: wordpress, plugins, customization, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to customize listing pro plugin and I need to change the priority of template hook which is added through plugin class.  like below

```
class TemplateHooks{
    static function init() {
        add_action("rtcl_listing_form", [__CLASS__, 'listing_gallery'], 20);
        add_action("rtcl_listing_form", [__CLASS__, 'listing_contact'], 30);
    }
 .......
}
```

Now I have tried the below code to change the priority of listing_gallery hook in child theme but it is not working.

```
remove_action("rtcl_listing_form", 'TemplateHooks', 'listing_gallery', 20);
add_action("rtcl_listing_form", 'TemplateHooks', 'listing_gallery', 6);
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong above as I'm learning the plugin customizations and make changes safe for future updates.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
remove_action( "rtcl_listing_form", "listing_gallery", 20 );
add_action("rtcl_listing_form", "new_function_listing_gallery", 10);
```

Thanks :)